# Importing contents of text file into MySQL using VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Good day everyone. I am trying to create a program that will transfer all of the contents of a text file into a database. So far, my code works, but my code only inserts the first line of the text file into the database. What should I add to solve the problem? I am noob at programming sorry.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim filename As String = "C:\Users\user\desktop\swipe.txt"
        Dim Query As String
        Dim data As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename)
        Dim Loc, _date, time, temp, id As String
        Loc = data.Substring(0, 3)
        _date = data.Substring(3, 8)
        time = data.Substring(11, 4)
        temp = data.Substring(15, 3)
        id = data.Substring(18, 3)
        Query = "INSERT INTO tbl_entrance_swipe VALUES ('" + Loc + "','" + _date + "','" + time + "','" + temp + "','" + id + "')"
        Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=cph;User ID=root;Password=;")
        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim sql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, con)
            sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Record is Successfully Inserted")
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            con.Close()
            MsgBox("Record is not Inserted" + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. I already edited it and I added the code already.

Comment: I think `ReadAllLines` would be better for this than `ReadAllText`.  Then you simply loop through the array returned by `ReadAllLines` and process each row one a a time.

Comment: When I try to use ReadAllLines, it says 'Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'String'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `File.ReadAllText` which reads the complete text of the file. You want to read line by line, therefore you can use `File.ReadLines`(deferred executed) or `File.ReadAllLines`(reads all into a `String()`).

You should also use sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection and incorrect implicit type conversions or localization issues. Finally, use the `Using` statement to ensure that all unmanaged resources are disposed (f.e. the connection gets closed even on error):

```
Dim filename As String = "C:\Users\user\desktop\swipe.txt"
Dim allLines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(filename)
Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_entrance_swipe VALUES (@Loc, @Date, @Time, @Temp, @Id)"

Using con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=cph;User ID=root;Password=;")
    con.Open()
    Using cmd As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(query, con)
        For Each line In allLines
            Dim loc, dt, time, temp, id As String
            loc = line.Substring(0, 3)
            dt = line.Substring(3, 8)
            time = line.Substring(11, 4)
            temp = line.Substring(15, 3)
            id = line.Substring(18, 3)
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            Dim pLoc As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@Loc", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
            pLoc.Value = loc
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pLoc)
            Dim pDate As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@Date", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
            pDate.Value = dt
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pDate)
            Dim pTime As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@Time", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
            pTime.Value = time
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pTime)
            Dim pTemp As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@Temp", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
            pTemp.Value = temp
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pTemp)
            Dim pId As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@Id", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
            pId.Value = id
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pId)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
        MsgBox("All records were inserted successfully")
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you a lot sir!!! Without you, I wouldn't have solved this problem. You are such an awesome person.

Comment: By the way sir, if it isn't too much, can I ask one more question?

Comment: You're welcome. But you should consider to change the types of your columns from varchar to f.e `datetime` for the `Date` column and `int` for the `Id` column. **Edit** Yes, of course.

Comment: Ok sir will do. My question is, how could I avoid data duplication? Because I'm planning to use insert this code on a button and whenever the button is pressed, the database automatically updates, because the text file that will be used will frequently be updated as well. How to avoid duplication?

Comment: @user3678904: you should either check before the insert (in the same query) if that record already exists or create  a unique index in the database and catch the specific exception which is raised. The former can be less efficient and creates a race condition on heavy load(many paralel inserts). I know how to catch the constraint-exception with SQL-Server (just catch `SqlException` and check it`s `Number` property), but i don't know how to do it on MySql. Here's the pseudo-sql for the former approach: `if not exists (select * from tbl_entrance_swipe s where s.Loc = @Loc and ..) INSERT INTO ..`

Comment: However, you should create a unique index anyway in the database to ensure that invalid data never  gets into your database.

Comment: Sir Tim may I ask again? I already changed the column in MySql, I already changed the date to date and the time to time and the ID to int but whenever I try to change them in the 'MySqlDbType.' type it says that it exceeded the paremeters. I changed it from 'MySqlDbType.VarChar' to 'MySqlDbType.Date' and so on and when I put Int or Integer in it says that it isn't a part of the MySqlDbType.

Comment: You have to pass the value with the  correct type, so if you have a datetime column you have to Parse the string to DateTime first, with an int column you have to parse it to int.